# ERROR 1524 (HY000): Plugin 'unix_socket' is not loaded - Laragon

Tags: mysql, mariadb, laragon

I'm migrating my production wordpress website to my local environment on Laragon.  I did the following:

Opened Laragon's Terminal: 
Menu > Laragon > Terminal
Ran this command:
`scp user@your-remote-host:/dump.sql C:/laragon/tmp/dump.sql`


Imported sql-dump to my local database:
`mysql -u root -p your-database < C:\laragon\tmp\dump.sql`

Then I cloned my git repo to the root at `C:\Laragon\www\`

Started it up and at first it displayed a replica of the live server's homepage, but gave an error when attempting to go to another page.

I stopped all services and when I restarted I was given the error `ERROR 1524 (HY000): Plugin 'unix_socket' is not loaded`

Then when I tried to do `mysql -u root -p` from the terminal I received the same error.

With the services started the web page now showed 'error establishing database' and displayed the `Error 1524`

Here is the output of `my.ini` file which is the same as `my.cnf`

```
[client]
#password=your_password
port=3306
socket=/tmp/mysql.sock

[mysqld]
port=3306
socket=/tmp/mysql.sock
key_buffer_size=256M
max_allowed_packet=512M
table_open_cache=256
sort_buffer_size=1M
read_buffer_size=1M
read_rnd_buffer_size=4M
myisam_sort_buffer_size=64M
thread_cache_size=8
datadir= "C:/laragon/data/mysql"
plugin-load-add = auth_socket.so


secure-file-priv=""
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp=1
datadir= "C:/laragon/data/mysql"


[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet=512M
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`unix_socket`, aka `auth_socket` is non-windows authentication plugin.

I'd start with the variable [skip-grant-tables](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysqld-options/#-skip-grant-tables) set, and [change the root authentication](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/authentication-from-mariadb-104/#altering-the-user-account-to-revert-to-the-previous-authentication-method) using:

```
ALTER USER root@localhost IDENTIFIED VIA mysql_native_password USING PASSWORD("verysecret")
```

Then remove the 'skip-grant-tables' option and restart.

Comment: when I try to access mysql from terminal I get the same error as when I try to access localhost on web browser.  Here's a screenshot of my terminal https://imgur.com/PYxYTLv

How can I run the sql command if I can't access the mysql command line

Comment: any ideas pretty stuck here?

Comment: `mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables`, opps, is a non-windows script so won't work on windows. Stop the mysql service in Windows. add `skip-grant-tables` into your my.ini file after `[mysqld]` and remove `plugin-load-add=...`. Then start the mysql service. Remove `skip-grant-tables` once `ALTER USER` has been done.